# Apache spark issue when spark.write is executed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I get below error while a spark.sql is executed and spark write is called. the sql does not haver any != operator. could not understand why it happens, anyone faced, could you please help?

```
(pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.InvalidObjectException: Unknown operator '!=' (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInputException; Request ID: 644b1f87-17e5-44a7-9345-791d2a3481e8; Proxy: null))
```

Comment: do you use an sql with !=, try <> instead